# I want a recursive function to check the order of an array using binary search

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

I wrote a recursive function to check an array of size n if it's in ascending order:

```
bool sortedAscending(const int*x, int n){
if (n == 0) return true;
if (x[n - 1] >= x[n - 2]) sortedAscending(x, n - 1);
else return false;
}
```

I want to do the same job but using the binary search algorithm (i.e. splitting the array in half each recursive call..). How can i do that?
Thank you.

Comment: The recursive function should take a pair of iterators - one to the beginning and one to the end of the range it is supposed to check. Then you can easily call it recursively with only halve the range.

Comment: Two problems. (1) `if (n <= 1) return true;` - an array of one element is always sorted; and the following code assumes there are at least two elements. (2) `return sortedAscending(x, n - 1);` - you are missing a `return` statement. Also, the last two lines could be simplified to `return x[n - 1] >= x[n - 2] && sortedAscending(x, n - 1);`

Comment: but what values do i compare each time i split?

Comment: Why do you want to use a less efficient method?

Comment: I am not sure if a "binary search" approach makes much sense in checking whether an array is sorted. You have to look at each element anyway so just looping straight through the array may even be faster. Do you want to do this just as an exercise or do you think it will be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool sortedAscending(const int* x, int n) {
  if (n <= 1) return true;
  int m = n / 2;
  return x[m-1] <= x[m] &&
         sortedAscending(x, m) &&
         sortedAscending(x + m, n - m);
}
```

Comment: is this a time complexity of O(n) ?

Comment: Yes. Did you expect something different?

Comment: But aren't we splitting half in each time? shouldn't it be O( log2(n) )?

Comment: Each part is half as long - but you now have two of them to check, so the amount of work remains the same. This approach merely rearranges the order in which comparisons are made - it still makes `n-1` comparisons. There is simply no way to check whether the array is sorted with fewer comparisons - as soon as you skip one, I can swap these two elements without you noticing.

Comment: @OsamaAref because binary search ignores each half and you only need 1 element it is so effective. For checking whether something is sorted you need to check **every** element in the vector... You can never go below O(n) when you need to actually "touch" every element.

Comment: Effectively this will likely be even slower than a normal loop through the array because you prevent prefetching with the "random" jumps around the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use pointers to the start and end of the candidate array. This is more consistent with the iterator style.

```
#include <iostream>

bool sortedAscending(const int* start, const int* end)
{
    if(start == end) return true;
    if(start + 1 == end) return true;
    auto halfDiff = (end - start) / 2;
    return *(start + halfDiff - 1) <= *(start + halfDiff) && sortedAscending(start, start + halfDiff) && sortedAscending(start + halfDiff, end);
}

int main()
{
    int array1[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int array2[] = {0,1,3,2,4,5,6,7};
    int array3[] = {0};
    int* array4 = nullptr;

    std::cout << "Array1: " << sortedAscending(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Array2: " << sortedAscending(std::begin(array2), std::end(array2)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Array3: " << sortedAscending(std::begin(array3), std::end(array3)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Array4: " << sortedAscending(array4, array4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```